# How can I get the sender of an external transaction?

Tags: blockchain

I need to verify each external transaction from the bsc blockchain to my address, if there is a match, send another action. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making a smart contract for this.

Solidity allows you to mark functions as `payable`. Here's a quick contract I made that allows you to perform an action when you receive ether:

```
contract PaymentForwarder is Ownable {
    function receive() public payable {
        owner().send(msg.value);
        // Then do some logic here
    }
}
```

Then, direct users to send ether to this contract.